# Reprex does not consult the current selection on RStudio Cloud

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse, reprex

I would like to use reprex on RStudio Cloud

The `reprex` manual says:

> When the clipboard is structurally unavailable, e.g., on RStudio
> Server or RStudio Cloud, reprex() consults the current selection
> instead of the clipboard

However, when I select my code in the script on RStudio Cloud and type `reprex::reprex()` in the console I get the following message:

````
No user-supplied code found … so we’ve made some up. You’re welcome!

``` r
sprintf("Happy %s!", weekdays(Sys.Date()))
#> [1] "Happy Thursday!"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>
````

Update1:
I get following error in the console if I copy the code into the clipboard and/or select it the script:

```
> reprex::reprex()

! No input provided and clipboard is not available.
```

Comment: can you pass the code in directly `reprex({rnorm(10)])`?

Comment: Yes this works. Is there a specific reason why selecting the text does not work? Do I maybe misunderstand "the current selection"?

Comment: I dunno, maybe you it can access the clipboard now so it never goes to active selection?

Comment: I think the clipboard is not available, see my update

Comment: @Nate I answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question got kindly answered by jennybc: https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex/issues/369#issuecomment-803229938

> This is a feature of dev reprex, so it is not yet on CRAN. Therefore,
> I suspect this is a version issue. (The pkgdown site reflects dev
> capabilities.)
>
> I will release these features to CRAN reprex soon.